# Tracking hostile facebook user's ip

Tags: facebook

I've seen most of the solutions to tracking a facebook user through chat; however, since I needed to delete my facebook account *because* of this person's actions, I can't just start a chat with them. They've done some pretty illegal/awful stuff, and I want to stop them from victimizing other people like they did to me. Is there a way to find out who they actually are and stuff if I have the address to their profile page?

Comment: Don't go vigilante, either file a complaint at Facebook or if they really did illegal stuff report them at your local police.

Comment: unfortunately, this jerk wasn't local. somewhere in Philidelphia, i think. The local police can't do anything until I actually have the monster's home address, but they said that the guy _would_ be arrested if found.

Comment: if you can bait them into clicking a link to a site you control, you can get their IP from your logs.